# Consolidated Reports of Condition and Income, naming convention

Tags: banking

Why are Banks' *Consolidated Reports of Condition and Income* also known as "FDIC Call Reports"?

Answer (score 4):

I posed the same question some years ago to a bank examiner (who had been a bank examiner for over 30 years) and his explanation was that every quarter the banks used to call the FDIC on the telephone and read out the numbers as soon as they were available (followed by a signed snail mail).

Now the files are sent electonically to the Federal Financial Institutions Examination Council (FFIEC).

Sounds plausible to me.